# Maven build executable jar/war from multi module Maven project with embedded Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web-applications, build

I have a little problem with a project idea I have (project has to be done for Uni, hence the backwards seeming approach).

You probably get the gist from the title, but let me explain in a little more detail. I want to create a little webApp from scratch, which should run in a embedded Tomcat or even Jetty if it doesn't work like I want it to.

The project structure I have now, would look something like this:

```
Root
|_ Module1
|_ Module2
|_ Setup
|_ ...
```

Root should just be the parent nothing interesting there. Module1 will contain some servlets and Module2 some JSPs.

My plan was to build both modules as WARs and in the Setup Module somehow deploy them into a new JAR that has an embedded Tomcat or Jetty instance in it. So that I am ultimately left with one JAR or WAR that I can just "start", get the server running and have my endpoints available.

I tried multiple things now with build tools and whatnot, but I guess my Maven game isn't as good as would like it to be, or I just think to complicated although it is easy, I just won't get it to work.

How can I get this to work? If it makes it easier I could merge Module1 and Module2 into one, but that isn't preferred. The Setup Module can also be removed of course.

Comment: is there a good reason to do that on your own instead of using soemthing like Spring Boot, Micronaut or Quarkus  ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Well I would love to use SpringBoot and consorts, but ultimetly it is a project for Uni and we have a limited pool of technology that we are allowed to use. So sadly this is technologically the best I can do